# return value of http request not conforming to prepared angular interface

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, interface, httprequest

i'm trying to understand why my first http request is conforming to my interface, but my second call is not.

my controller :

```
this.qs.getCategoryNames()
.then((res: AllCategoryTab) => {
  this.questionCategory = res;
  this.qs.getSurveyByName(this.questionCategory.names[0])
  .then((result: AllQuestions)=> { //result not conforming to AllQuestion interface
    this.allQuestions = result; //allQuestions not conforming to interface
    this.categoryIndex = 1;
    console.log(typeof this.allQuestions.questions); //show "undefined"
  }).catch(function(err){
    throw err;
  });
})
.catch(function(err) {
  return err;
});
```

my service :

```
getCategoryNames(): Promise<Object> {
const url = `${this.baseUrl}/survey/names`;
return this.http.get(url).toPromise()
.then(function(result) {
  console.log(typeof "result 1 ", result) //type is string
  return result;
}).catch(function(err) {
  throw err;
});

getSurveyByName(name: string): Promise<Object> {
const url = `${this.baseUrl}/survey/${name}`;
return this.http.get(url).toPromise()
.then(function(result) {
  console.log(typeof "result 2 ", result) // type is string
    return result;
  }).catch(function(err) {
   throw err;
 });
```

the interfaces theoretically look like the data that i retrive from the server :

```
export interface AllCategoryTab {
  names: string
}

export interface Questions {
  answered: boolean,
  name: string,
  question: string,
  types: Array<string>,
  value: boolean
}

export interface Condition {
  name: string,
  number: number,
  value: boolean
}

export interface ConditionsObject {
  condition: Array<Condition>
}

export interface AllQuestions {
  questions: Array<Questions>,
  conditions:Array<ConditionsObject>,
  potentialDisorders: string
}
```

since i'm using typescript, all the types are set up in advance, but it seems that when i try to put the result of my promise into my variable, it stays how i receive it and it doesn'transform to how i want it to look

Comment: Typescript **does not exist at runtime**. It cannot do any casting or conversion. You have to tell it what you're _actually going_ to receive, not what you'd _like_ to.

Comment: so, instead of putting result into my made up variable in my controller, i should already in my service be receiving with everything prepared ? ps: i understood you wrong, my interface are made exacly how the data looks in my server, so it's not really what i "want" but it's what i expect it too look like